# Microsoft Access inventory report

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access database with four tables. One the holds the locations of our remote sites and the other three are tables of equipment, their location, and their configuration. For example:

Table1 : Locations

- Location1, Address1
- Location2, Address2
- Location3, Address3

Table2: Equipment1

- Serial1, Location1
- Serial2, Location3
- Serial3, Locaiton3

Table3: Equipment2

- Serial1, Locaiton2

Table4: Equopment3

- Serial1, Location1
- Serial2, Location2
- Serial3, Location3

How can I create a report that lists the equipment at each location:

Location1:

- Equipment1, Serial1
- Equipment3, Serial1

Location2:

- Equipment2, Serial1
- Equipmetn3, Serial2

Location3:

- Equipment1, Serial2
- Equipment1, Serial3
- Equipment3, Serial3

I do have the locations in each of the equipment tables related to the ID of the Locations table.

I have been able to make nice looking reports for each piece of equipment. But, I would like most to have an "Inventory" report like shown above. Any suggestions on even where to start would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why have you got three tables of equipment? If they are different types then have one table with an additional EquipType identifier . Then your query becomes very simple.

You have a problem because your data isn't stored in a normalised fashion.

Comment: I did it this way because each equipment type has its own configuration that don't apply to each other. Really my tables are: Equipment1, Serial 1, Option1; Equipment2, Serial1, OptionA. When I pull up reports for Equipment1, I only want it to have fields for Option1, Option2; when I pull up a report for Equipment2, I only want it to have fields for OptionA, OptionB. If that makes any sense. Those reports are easy, Its just I also want reports on location for any type of Equipment with their associated options, if any.

Comment: You shouldn't have fields such as option1, option2, option99 as your design will soon get unmanageable. 

You will end up designing a specific report for every equipment type and then adding a new one when something else crops up.

You should have an equipment type and then a option type and a junction table to join each equipment type to the relevant  options for it.

Whilst harder to set up initially it gives you complete flexibility, going forwards.

Comment: @Minty You are right! I have had a lot to learn about normalizing databases! I now have one table for equipment, one for Equipment manufacture, one for Equipment type, and one for locations with each field in the equipment table being a lookup to another table. I have designed a form with a combo box that looks like a drop-down menu with all the locations listed. After choosing a location, a script is run that shows all the equipment at that location in a sub-form - which is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would do a union query, something like

```
Select "Equipment1" as SourceTable, Serial, Location from [Equipment1]
Union all select "Equipment2", Serial, Location from [Equipment2]
Union all select "Equipment3", Serial, Location from [Equipment3]
```

Save this query and you can use it in another query or report to sort and display as needed.